# Which is the best Class for Download and upload data from iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am developing application in iPhone, Where i need to download and upload data from webservice. Please advice me which is the best class or Framework to achieve this and also please let me know which is the best xmlparser.

Answer (score 2):

you can use asihttprequest and asihttpresponse for establishing connection use restful api and nxxml parser for parsing the data comes from server
thanks

Answer (score 0):

NSXMLParser is a SAX parser included by default with the iPhone SDK.
TouchXML is an NSXML style DOM XML parser for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

If your web service has the ability to return json, I would highly recommend doing so and using http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/. Especially if you have a complex XML document.

As for connecting to the service, it's pretty straightforward - all you need is a method to handle the connections. While there are 'frameworks' out there, it's as simple as creating a method such as "getDataFromService:(nsstring *)param1" and within that method issuing a request.

I think the bigger question you'll need to answer is how to authenticate with the service, if required.  If the service uses OAuth, http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/ is a great framework.